# How to use Jquery to update textarea value in react app

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm building a Chrome extension that layers over a 3rd party react website. I am attempting to update the value of a textarea within that app using the following code:

```
$('textarea').val("Text to go in textarea.");
```

The code successfully updates the textarea however once the user clicks on the textarea, the DOM seems to regenerate and the value becomes blank.

What is the best way to update the value within the textarea so that it remains even once the user clicks and DOM regenerates? I am not a react expert however my guess is that the textarea is tied to the state. Is there any way to update that from my own jquery within my chrome extension?

Just to be clear, the textarea belongs to a 3rd party website/react app that I have no control over. I'm trying to manipulate it from my own google chrome extension. I thought the easiest way would be to somehow simulate actual typing in order to make the react app think the user typed my input however I searched around and could not find a way to do that.

Comment: Have u tried triggering the `onChange` event of the textarea ? It really depends on how the 3rd party app is designed. Some could work on `keypress`, 'keydown` or `keyup` mostly on `change`. So you can try triggering these events and check.

Comment: You don't, jQuery does not belong in a React app.

Comment: your method will fail as the change has only been made to the dom, any change in state or props will re-render the component and wipe out your changes

Comment: You should maintain the value internally into the `state` and whenever your component re-renders you should replace `textarea` value with your `state value` in `ComponentWillMount` or `ComponentDidMount` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use set value of `DOM` Html element:

```
document.getElementById("textarea").value = "Johnny Bravo";
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @Panther's suggestion, you can set the value as you have done above and then trigger the onChange or keypress event etc to save the changes in either state or props. Now since React uses synthetic events , you need to trigger then as shown.

```
$('textarea').val("Text to go in textarea.");

$.each(document.getElementsByTagName("textarea"),(index,Element)=>{
    let event = new Event("change"); // repeat for keypressup,down,input etc.
    Element.dispatchEvent(event);
});
```